# Angular - MatDialog, Is need to unsubscribe to keyboard events?

Tags: angular, mat-dialog

When I subscribe to angular mat-dialog, to I need to unsubscribe it after close the dialog or in other any place? Or when the dialog is destroyed - the GC collect also its keyboard events subsribers?

```
    dialogRef.keydownEvents().subscribe(event => {
        // do something...
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you needn't. This events are smart in `Material` and do unsubscribe for you.